# What are joined and unjoined fonts?

Tags: technique-identification

I'm recently learning font design and typography.
I found that even a same font style can have two font versions: joined and unjoined. I'd tried to google it, but got no explanation.

What's the different between those fonts? How do I use them?

I would greatly appreciate it if anyone can help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**A 'joined' font may refer to a type of [script typeface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Script_typeface)**, where all characters of a word are connected by single lines. Most so-called 'handwriting' fonts make use of these glyphs. And some fonts, such as your example, may offer an additional isolated glyph version, like this font:

[image: Debbie Hepplewhite font, joined and unjoined]

As the name 'script' implies, it is derived from handwriting, and can still generally be seen in writing exercises in primary schools.

---

Alternatively, **those terms might be referring to fonts that offer versions with and without ligatures**, the usually curvy lines that connect certain sets of characters:

[image: Example of several ligatures. Picture via Wikipedia, Public Domain]

> In writing and typography, a ligature occurs where two or more
>   graphemes or letters are joined as a single glyph.
>   <sup>[source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Typographic_ligature)</sup>

Like script typeface, ligatures derive from handwriting.
A famous common example is the ampersand `&`.

---

**Usage**

Whenever you come across a font with different character sets, they are offered as separate fonts (under the same family name, sometimes archived together in *.rar*, *.zip*, or *.7z* files, which have to be unpacked first).
You install the fonts, and they will show up in your editing programs as separate fonts (e.g., using the example above, the fonts will show up like "Debbie Hepplewhite Print" and "Debbie Hepplewhite Joinit").

---

If you have any other questions, let me know, and I will update my answer.

Comment: I would definitely assume they mean scripts where the characters join. Some advanced ones have different join patterns so that a high join (like what comes out of a lowercase o or b) joins the next character differently than one coming from below (like from a j or g). Ligatures, of course, originate from the same phenomenon, but usually refer to conventionalized pairs of characters like & for "et" or ß for "ss" (where the first s is a "long s" in traditional script).

Comment: Going meta here: With the current discussion on whether to automatically send stuff to Graphic Arts because it is about digital production... This is very clearly a Graphic Arts related question. Why was it not sent over? (I have no problem with OP's question, but it seems inconsistent)

Comment: @rebusB Fonts are not inherently digital, and as a form of art I believe they are very welcome here as well.

Comment: @Joachim Good point. But it is not about their digital nature. They sit squarely in the field of Graphic Arts...

Comment: @rebusB Yeah, you're right. You can VTC if you want to, as indeed it would be a better fit for Graphic Design. For some reason the only and very broad tag suddenly changed my mind completely :)

Comment: @Joachim  No, I am not interested in closing the question. It just provided a foil to the digital goes to GA issue.